# Properties of Search Declaration in VS2013 for Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have used search contract in my application and it also works great.

But there are properties for *Search declaration* in `Package.appxmanifest` like

- `Executable`
- `Entry point`
- `Start page`

What do they mean? I tried putting some values in it but no use.

[image: Parameters of search declaration]

can anyone please explain what these options are there for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executable & Entry Point are specific to C++ apps where you need to specify the executable and entry point to run when the contract is activated.

The Start Page is specific to JavaScript-based apps - where you specify the starting HTML page.

Comment: thank you , I guess no one give much attention to these properties as I could not found any details about it on web or MSDN

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which values are needed for those three box (executable, entry point, start page) but I can say that:

If you remember, Windows 8 was providing a global search us (write something on startscreen's searchbox and select an app to start search).

Maybe these values could be required to provide global search api to Windows.